# Substrings and rounding in go

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Print("loaded\n")
    var xInp = bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin) 
    var yInp = bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

    fmt.Print("insert y value: ")
    yInp.Scan()
    fmt.Print("Insert x value: ")
    xInp.Scan()

    q, err := strconv.Atoi(yInp.Text())
    w, err := strconv.Atoi(xInp.Text())

    var slope = q/w
    fmt.Print(slope)
    fmt.Print(err)
}
```

I am trying to make this code have a substring. When I type in as y, 190. And x as 13. The answer, the program claims is 14. But that is not true. It is a infinite decimal. Obviously I do not want to show the whole decimal. But I do want to show 4 decimal places. for example 190/13 = 14.6153. It is also fine if you know how to round the decimal. That probably would be better. But both are fine.

Comment: Not sure what substrings have to do with the question but your problem is that you are using integers (`Atoi`).  The result of an integer division is an integer (in many languages, not just Go).  Use floating point arithmetic and once you have your floating point answer you can think about formatting it...  Try `strconv.ParseFloat(xInp.Text(), 64)` instead of `Atoi` for starters.  Unrelated you probably just want a single scanner and use `ReadLine` or something.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood you want just two divide two numbers and output the result (it has nothing to do substrings).

The problem that you divide integer by integer and therefore gets back an integer. The main changes that I have done in your program are:

```
var slope = float64(q)/float64(w)  // converted both ints to floats
fmt.Printf("%.4f\n", slope)   // printed float to 4 decimal points
```

Basically here it is:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    var xInp = bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    var yInp = bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("insert y value: ")
    yInp.Scan()
    fmt.Print("Insert x value: ")
    xInp.Scan()
    q, err := strconv.Atoi(yInp.Text())
    w, err := strconv.Atoi(xInp.Text())
    var slope = float64(q)/float64(w)
    fmt.Printf("%.4f\n", slope)
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Comment: This was very helpfull, But I am new to go. So can you explain to me what float64 means, and what %.2f\n means. (I understand what \n means)

Comment: @liam I wrote that in the comment. float64 converts your integer to float value. `"%.2f" ` formats your string: read it here https://gobyexample.com/string-formatting

Comment: I understand that it converts it to a float. But what is a float. Go is my first programming language that I really am getting into. What does f stand for. I understand that it dictates formatting. But what does each indevidual part do? Please answer as if you were speaking to a programming noob. Because thats what I am.

Comment: float means rational numbers (with 2.3, 5.001). If this is your first programming language, I recommend you to start reading documentation and very basic tutorials: https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1 https://gobyexample.com/. Otherwise you will suffer.